# GitHub: Is it common practice for a business to store solutions on there?

Tags: github

I'm looking at Github and it looks great. I see there are business accounts you can set up to version control your work. I know there is a lot of open source stuff on there, but is it common practice for businesses to store solutions on there? And more importantly, is it safe? As the solutions are not to be viewed by anyone else.

Comment: You could always ask your developers and see what they prefer working with, Git / Subversion / mercurial etc, then work out which hosting solution you'll go for.

Comment: I'm not sure there's an objective/definitive answer to this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How secure would github hosting be for private repositories?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989837/how-secure-would-github-hosting-be-for-private-repositories)

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, I just transitioned my company's source to GitHub, using private repositories. Also, I've been keeping commercial products of my own on GitHub in the same way for some time

It's working great. Your account has a list of 'contributors' for each repository, which controls who can view / commit to each one.

The business accounts on GitHub are suitable for you if you do not want to store your code on someone else's server. Sign up for this if you want to keep your repositories "behind the firewall" by installing the software on your own server.

References:

- [GitHub Enterprise](https://enterprise.github.com/) (this is the "business" plan)
- [GitHub Security](https://help.github.com/security/)

Answer (score 2):

Concerning safety - there was a similar question a few months ago.
Check it (and my answer there :-) out:
[How safe is it to host sensitive data on repository sites like github, bitbucket, etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926744/how-safe-is-it-to-host-sensitive-data-on-repository-sites-like-github-bitbucket)

I don't *know* if it's common practice for companies to store their code online...but I guess that a lot of companies don't like the idea of hosting their intellectual property at some third party.

Probably "company culture" makes a big part of it.
I'd say that "hip" internet startups are more likely to host their stuff online than "conservative" enterprises/"non-techy" companies.

Some of the "hip internet" companies (for example [Facebook](https://github.com/facebook), [Twitter](https://github.com/twitter), [GitHub](https://github.com/github)...) at least have open-sourced part of their stuff, but I don't know which of them also host their private stuff there and which don't.
*(except GitHub, I read somewhere that they host ALL of their stuff themselves...makes sense :-)*

Another example: Headspring Software (where quite a few known .NET developers work) [runs nearly completely on online services](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/running-headspring-systems-on-cloud-services/).
The linked blog post doesn't explicitly mention where they host their source code, but I wanted to mention this example anyway because of all the other stuff they have outsourced.
 Many "conservative" companies wouldn't even want their e-mail/calendar/sales data at some third-party provider in the cloud...let alone their source code.